# The rank of a matrix, dependent on the value of $t$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

I'm trying to analyse the rank of the following matrix, for $t\in \mathbb{R}$.

$$\begin{bmatrix}
    t+3 & 5 & 6 \\
    -1 & t-3 & -6 \\
    1 & 1 & t+4
\end{bmatrix}$$

With $R_1\leftrightarrow R_3$, $-(t+3)R_1+R_3 \rightarrow R_3$, $R_1+R_2 \rightarrow R_2$, and finally $-R_2+R_3\rightarrow R_3$. I get

$$\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 1 & t-4 \\
    0 & t-2 & t-2 \\
    0 & 0 & -t^2-8t-4
\end{bmatrix}$$

And this makes that when $t=2$ or $t=2(-2 \pm \sqrt{3})$. However, these values are not what they are supposed to give(-2,2,4). Where did I make a mistake? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It would be helpful to know what you think are the values that you should get?

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea.: I always like to start out with the determinant:  $t^3-4 t^2-4 t+16 = 0 \implies t = -2, 2, 4$.

Comment: After your first step we have

$$ A = \left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
  { - 1}&{t - 3}&{ - 6} \\ 
  {t + 3}&5&6 \\ 
  1&1&{t - 4} 
\end{array}} \right] $$

After the second, 
$$ A = \left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
  { - 1}&{t - 3}&{ - 6} \\ 
  {t + 3}&5&6 \\ 
  {t + 4}&{1 - {t^2} + 9}&{7t + 14} 
\end{array}} \right] $$

After 3rd,

$$ A = \left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
  { - 1}&{t - 3}&{ - 6} \\ 
  {t + 2}&{t + 2}&0 \\ 
  {t + 4}&{1 - {t^2} + 9}&{7t + 14} 
\end{array}} \right] $$

Comment: And after final step,

$$ A = \left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
  { - 1}&{t - 3}&{ - 6} \\ 
  {t + 2}&{t + 2}&0 \\ 
  2&{ - t - {t^2} + 9 - 1}&{7t + 14} 
\end{array}} \right] $$

So I assume you meant $-R_2+R_1 \to R_2$ in the penultimate step. From there moving forward with $-R_2+R_3\to R_3$ and $(t+4)R_1+R_2 \to R_2$ gives,
$$
A = \left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
  { - 1}&{t - 3}&{ - 6} \\ 
  0&{{t^2} - 4}&{ - 6t - 12} \\ 
  0&{ - {t^2} + t + 2}&{7t + 12} 
\end{array}} \right] $$

Comment: @Moo You're right, but in this exercise, I cannot use the determinant...

Comment: @IvanAbraham First I would like to thank you for the efforts that show in your detailed comments. There's a typo in my first elementary operation. It should be $R_1 \leftrightarrow R_3$. I apologise

Comment: @IvanAbraham I've also corrected one typo in the original matrix

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea.: I understand, but it can be used to make sure your RREF and conclusions are correct.

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea.: When you do the RREF, you had better see those three roots - or you missed something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the last elementary operation. I should have done $R_2+R_3\rightarrow R_3$

Then I would have obtained
$$\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 1 & t-4 \\
    0 & t-2 & t-2 \\
    0 & 0 & -t^2-6t-8
\end{bmatrix}$$
Giving the correct values for $t$.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
\begin{bmatrix}
    t+3 & 5 & 6 \\
    -1 & t-3 & -6 \\
    1 & 1 & t+4
\end{bmatrix}
&\to
\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 1 & t+4 \\
    -1 & t-3 & -6 \\
    t+3 & 5 & 6 \\
\end{bmatrix}
&&R_1\leftrightarrow R_3
\\
&\to
\begin{bmatrix}
1   & 1   & t+4 \\
0   & t-2 & t-2 \\
t+3 & 5   & 6 \\
\end{bmatrix}
&&R_2\gets R_2+R_1
\\
&\to
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1   & t+4 \\
0 & t-2 & t-2 \\
0 & 2-t & -t^2-7t-6 \\
\end{bmatrix}
&&R_3\gets R_3-(t+3)R_1
\\
&\to
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1   & t+4 \\
0 & t-2 & t-2 \\
0 & 0   & -t^2-6t-8 \\
\end{bmatrix}
&&R_3\gets R_3+R_1
\end{align}
The roots of $-t^2-6t-8$ are $-2$ and $-4$.

- If $t\notin\{2,-2,-4\}$ the rank is $3$.
- If $t=2$, the rank is $2$.
- If $t=-2$ or $t=-4$, the rank is $2$.

The result you're given is wrong. The numbers $-2$, $2$ and $4$ are the eigenvalues of
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix}
3 & 5 & 6 \\
-1 & -3 & -6 \\
1 & 1 & 4
\end{bmatrix}
$$
and your case is finding the eigenvalues of $-A$.